# Clustered Index or Non clustered index on non primary key column?

Tags: sql, indexing

In my situation I have a table (well many tables) that are using an identity column as their primary key.  They will also contain a unique int column RecordID.  90% of the time RecordID will be used to search for a record.  The only reason the ID identity column even exists is to keep things consistent across our system.  In this case should I drop the clustered index from the ID column and add it to the RecordID column?  Then add a non-clustered index to the primary key ID in the rare case it will be used to get a record.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your queries are singleton seek on RecordID (ie. `WHERE RecordID=...`) then I wouldn't change it. Is true that a clustered index on it will be faster, but would only be noticeable on really really hot cases.

What I would consider for a change it would be if you have range queries (`BETWEEN`, `<` or `>`). Range scans could benefit more significantly from clustered index, as a non-clustered index may be subject to the [index tipping point](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/category/The-Tipping-Point.aspx).

Another thing to consider is if you have sort requirements that could be satisfied by this clustered index (ORDER BY in queries, or GROUP BY, or [ranking functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx) like ROW_NUMBER with ORDER by clause). A clustered index would help these better.